# JEE 6 Load all beans of one type - WebSphere

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, websphere, java-ee-6

My use case is that I have multiple classes implementing an interface and at runtime I want an instance for each of them. I found solutions which utilizes CDI for that with `Instance` combined with `@Any` qualifier. The following example works fine in Glassfish, but not in WebSphere 8.

The interface I'm lookng for:

```
public interface TestIf {
    String test();
}
```

One example implementation:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class TestA implements TestIf {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Another example implementation:

```
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

@Stateless
public class TestB implements TestIf {

    @Override
    public String test() {
        return getClass().getName();
    }
}
```

Glassfish does not require a `beans.xml` it works with the bean annotation fine, but WebSphere complains that CDI is not enabled, unless it is pressent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

I made a simple startup bean to try:

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.ejb.Singleton;
import javax.ejb.Startup;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Any;
import javax.enterprise.inject.Instance;
import javax.inject.Inject;

@Startup
@Singleton
public class Start {

    @Any
    @Inject
    private Instance<TestIf> providers;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(">>>>> FOO " + providers);

        for (final TestIf b : providers) {
            System.out.println(">>>>> " + b.test());
        }
    }

}
```

In Glassfish it works:

```
...
Info:   >>>>> FOO
Info:   >>>>> TestB
Info:   >>>>> TestA
...
```

In Websphere I got the error:

```
E   CWOWB0102E: A JCDI error has occurred: Api type [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
for injection into 
Field Injection Point, field :  private javax.enterprise.inject.Instance Start.providers, Bean Owner : [-495517893,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[Start,java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
InjectionType   :  [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>]
Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>,Type Closures : [Iterable<TestIf>, javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>, Provider<interface TestIf>, class java.lang.Object],Annotations : [@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()],Java Member Name : providers]
Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]]
E   CNTR0190E: The Start startup singleton session bean in the ejb.jar module failed initialization with exception:
javax.ejb.NoSuchEJBException: An error occurred during initialization of singleton session bean foo.ear#foo.ejb.jar#Start, resulting in the discarding of the singleton instance.; nested exception is: javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
for injection into 
Field Injection Point, field :  private javax.enterprise.inject.Instance Start.providers, Bean Owner : [-495517893,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[Start,java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
InjectionType   :  [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>]
Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>,Type Closures : [Iterable<interface TestIf>, javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>, Provider<interface TestIf>, class java.lang.Object],Annotations : [@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()],Java Member Name : providers]
Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]]
javax.ejb.EJBException: Injection failure; nested exception is: javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
for injection into 
Field Injection Point, field :  private javax.enterprise.inject.Instance Start.providers, Bean Owner : [-495517893,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[Start,java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
InjectionType   :  [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>]
Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>,Type Closures : [Iterable<interface TestIf>, javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>, Provider<interface TestIf>, class java.lang.Object],Annotations : [@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()],Java Member Name : providers]
Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]]
javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException: Api type [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance] is not found with the qualifiers 
Qualifiers: [@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]
for injection into 
Field Injection Point, field :  private javax.enterprise.inject.Instance Start.providers, Bean Owner : [-495517893,Name:null,WebBeans Type:MANAGED,API Types:[Start,java.lang.Object],Qualifiers:[javax.enterprise.inject.Any,javax.enterprise.inject.Default]]
InjectionType   :  [javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>]
Annotated       :  [Annotated Field,Base Type : javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>,Type Closures : [Iterable<interface TestIf>, javax.enterprise.inject.Instance<TestIf>, Provider<interface TestIf>, class java.lang.Object],Annotations : [@javax.inject.Inject(), @javax.enterprise.inject.Any()],Java Member Name : providers]
Qualifiers      :  [[@javax.enterprise.inject.Any()]]
```

The Glassfish runs with Java 8 "inside" NetBeans. WebSphere runs with IBM JDK 8 "inside" Eclipse. For brevity I stripped the package names of my classes.

Comment: if glassfish doesn't require a beans.xml that means Glassfish is at EE7, not EE6.  If you want to compare EE7 to EE7, WAS 9.0 is EE7 compliant.

Comment: Ok, that's why WebSphere require the `beans.xml`. Anyway, I added the `beans.xml`. AFAIK I did everything JEE 6 compliant. WAS 9 is no option.

Comment: I've tried to do a more simple injection with only one implementation. That also does not work. It looks like CDI does not work in any way in WAS 8. Do. I have to enable it via the admin console? The documentation does not say so as far as I see.